# Retarget error from Mixamo to readyplayer.me

Tags: animation, auto-rig-pro

[image]

I created character from readyplayer.me and rigged it using Auto Rig Pro.
When I tried retargeting a mixamo animation, the arms always end up in an incorrect orientation.

Any way to fix this. I really don't want to manually fixing this for each retarget in the graph editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue by resetting your model into a T pose. The auto rig pro won't work unless you have your model in a T Pose because of offsets.